# IIS Authorization Rules not working for WCF (but authentication is ok)

Tags: wcf, iis

I have IIS authentication setup and working for my WCF web service (under IIS\Authentication settings I have enabled Windows authentication, disabled anonymous, configured Windows transport on server and client) and it's working, and the client is passing through their credentials correctly.

However, under IIS\Authorisation rules (right next to Authentication icon) I put some rules in, but they are being ignored.

Do you have to do something special with authorisation with WCF as I just assumed IIS would check the user's details against the rules and allow/deny them.

I'd rather do it through IIS than in code as my needs are very simple.

thanks.

Comment: what rules are you trying to enforce? can you show us the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had the same issue.  The short answer is that you need to use **ASP.NET Compatibility Mode**.  I have a more detailed answer on the following question: [Why won't Authorization Rules in IIS restrict access to my WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67712447/why-wont-authorization-rules-in-iis-restrict-access-to-my-wcf-service)

Hopefully this is helpful to somebody else!  It had me scratching my head for a number of weeks...